How to Clone a Single SSD to a RAID 1 Array?
I have a 1TB SSD with Windows 11 installed and lots of software.
I want to set up a RAID 1 (mirror) configuration.
I installed two empty 1TB SSDs and configured RAID 1 in the BIOS.
I'm trying to clone the disk with Windows onto the RAID 1 using CloneZilla, but it shows the three disks separately, and I can't select RAID 1 as the destination.
I also tried setting up RAID 1 with one full disk and one empty disk, but the data isn't copying over, even though I was told the motherboard would handle it automatically.

"but it shows the three disks separately" – I think this means the RAID is a fake RAID. It will work as RAID only if the OS (or Clonezilla, or whatever you boot) understands it; in other words it needs a driver. I guess even if Clonezilla understood it and you managed to clone your Windows, the cloned Windows might not understand.

clonezilla works at the filesystem level and is designed to do a direct clone from one disk to another. The best approach (someone correct me if i'm wrong), is to do a fresh Win11 installation onto your raid and then copy all your important data across to it.
